# Update fixture column not working in case of ThinkingSphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am writing thinking-Sphinx test cases. i have following test case

```
  test 'z' do

    app = applications(:one)
    message = messages(:two)
    message.update_column(:messagable_id, app.id)
    message.update_column(:comment, 'This is second message')

    ThinkingSphinx::Test.start
    sign_in @user
    ThinkingSphinx::Test.index

    get :index, company_id: @company.id,  qc: 'Messages', q: 'Body | second', format: 'json'
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal decode_json_response(@response)['apps'].count, 2
end
```

> **In my case message.update_column is not taking affect**, instead if i make the same changes in messages fixture then i got my test case
>   pass.

**Is there any specific reason why update_column is not taking affect with thinking sphinx** because everywhere else update_column is working just fine.

Comment: Are you using transactional fixtures for your tests?

Comment: Yes, i am using transnational fixtures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL-backed indices (and it seems you are, if you're calling `index`?), then you can't use transactional fixtures for tests which involve Sphinx/Thinking Sphinx, because Sphinx's indexing happens via separate connections to your database, and the transaction that's operating within the scope of your test isn't available.

[The documentation](http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/testing.html#using-non-transactional-fixtures) covers the possibility of using DatabaseCleaner and using the deletion approach for tests that involve Sphinx - though the example is for RSpec, and it looks like you're using a different testing library, so I'm not quite sure of the specifics of how to implement this in your case.

Comment: I am using rails minitest. The solution i found was this: make use_transactional_fixtures = false